# How to Switch Between Ryzen Integrated and Nvidia Graphics - Arch

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu

I've got an Asus GA503QS which a Ryzen 9 5xxx and an RTX 3080. This CPU has an integrated Renoir GPU.

I've installed the latest NVidia drivers and but the Renoir GPU seems to be getting used.

I've only been able to find information on Intel + NVidia (Optimus) on the forums, so is there any way to get switchable graphics working with an AMD + NVidia combination?

Answer (score 0):

I cut/pasted the paragraph below from the Steam forums where I wrote these instructions for another person who has been having problems similar to what you are describing. These instructions are mostly centered around describing how I was able to get the RTX3080 in my GA503QS to kick in at the right time so that I can get VR working on this system.

There is someone on Youtube that made this excellent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6x-RQ7ZBsQ), showing how to tweak graphics and service settings so that everything works automagically like it's supposed to, but for whatever reason, though his video did help a lot, I still have to do the little dance described in the paragraph below to get the two seemingly competing graphics cards to play nice on my system.  I know I'm about six months late to the party, so if you happened to come upon any useful revelations since then, I would love to not have to rig my nearly three thousand dollar laptop each session to work correctly, ...but if not, I hope that this info is at least somewhat helpful in helping you find a viable solution...

> In order to get the Oculus Quest to even be able to access Steam VR/Steam Home I have a fairly straight forward little routine I go through that goes something like this:
>
> First, I use the hotkey combo of the [Windows] key and X which brings up a list menu. I click "Device Manager", then expand "Display Adapters" in the tree. (Because this machine has both a Radeon integrated graphics card as well as the RTX 3080, both display adapters are shown). I right click, then disable, "AMD Radeon Graphics". The common, "Are you sure?" prompt by Windows pops up. I click, "yes", and then the screen flickers and the resolution drops fairly significantly. I then restart Windows and log back in. Again I use the key combo of the [Windows] key and X, and open "Device Manager". The, "Display Adapters", tree should already be expanded which is common when a device is either not working correctly or has been disabled. I then right click and re-enable, "AMD Radeon Graphics", which should cause the resolution to go back to normal again, then close Device Manager. It should be fairly smooth sailing from there. I know it looks like a lot when written out in text, but the whole process takes little more than a minute. Of course mileage and computers vary, so it may take more or even less time for others to whom this little routine applies. From my eyeball crushing hours of researching and reading, the issue of the integrated graphics card trying to take on the load of the more powerful graphics card is common in the Asus ROG laptops with dual graphics cards. I also have an Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 with the RTX 2060 and the same Radeon Integrated graphics, and the above routine somewhat applies to it as well, but strangely only every once in a while. Why can't the little one be the one that acts up as apposed the one that costs almost twice as much? ....Sigh... I'm pretty sure we all know the answer to that question. This sort of thing has been spoken of many times by the great profit Murphy. ...Smart man that Murphy. His laws seem as immutable as ones like the 2nd law of thermodynamics and the inverse square law, ....but I digress.

Comment: I have no idea why part of my post showed up all giant and bold. ‍♂️

Comment: You need a blank line between your paragraph and the bottom (attempt at) a horizontal line, or the markdown parser thinks it's an underline for a heading. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#headers